# Sort Multidimensional Array in specific order

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

im trying to sort a Multidimensional Array in a specific order. My Array looks like this:

```
array (size=4)
  '1574764780' => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => 
        array (size=3)
          'name' => string 'x' (length=1)
          'nr' => string '5' (length=1)
          'color' => string 'red' (length=3)
      1 => 
        array (size=3)
          'name' => string 'y' (length=1)
          'nr' => string '6' (length=1)
          'color' => string 'yellow' (length=6)
      2 => 
        array (size=3)
          'name' => string 'z' (length=1)
          'nr' => string '4' (length=1)
          'color' => string 'blue' (length=4)
      3 => 
        array (size=3)
          'name' => string 'a' (length=1)
          'nr' => string '2' (length=1)
          'color' => string 'green' (length=5)
  '36879010280' => 
           ...
```

And i need to sort it that the array with the color red is in the first place, green in second etc: order of the key color should be like:

`red,green,blue,yellow`.

But there might not be a green in every Array. Then it should be like:

`red,blue,yellow`

Output should be:

```
array (size=4)
  '1574764780' => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => 
        array (size=3)
          'name' => string 'x' (length=1)
          'nr' => string '5' (length=1)
          'color' => string 'red' (length=3)
      1 => 
        array (size=3)
          'name' => string 'a' (length=1)
          'nr' => string '2' (length=1)
          'color' => string 'green' (length=5)
      2 => 
        array (size=3)
          'name' => string 'z' (length=1)
          'nr' => string '4' (length=1)
          'color' => string 'blue' (length=4)
      3 => 
        array (size=3)
          'name' => string 'y' (length=1)
          'nr' => string '6' (length=1)
          'color' => string 'yellow' (length=6)
  '36879010280' => 
           ...
```

I have been searching for hours but couldnt find a nice way to do this. 
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Create a new array based with keys on color. Sort the new array by keys.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar but I have only one dimension array. I hope this will help you

```
usort($ar, function ($a, $b) use ($order) {
    $pos_a = array_search($a['color'], $order);
    $pos_b = array_search($b['color'], $order);
    return $pos_a - $pos_b;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing this way. Code not pretty but you can refer to it. Hope it helps.

```
$arr = array(
  '1574764780' => array(
        0 => array(
            'name' =>  'x',
            'nr' =>  '5',
            'color' =>  'red'
        ),
        1 => array (
            'name' =>  'a',
            'nr' =>  '2',
            'color' =>  'green'),
        2 => array (
            'name' =>  'z',
            'nr' =>  '4',
            'color' =>  'blue'),
        3 => array (
            'name' =>  'y',
            'nr' =>  '6',
            'color' =>  'yellow')
    ),
    '1574764781' => array(
        0 => array(
              'name' =>  'x',
              'nr' =>  '5',
              'color' =>  'blue'
        ),
        1 => array (
            'name' =>  'a',
            'nr' =>  '2',
            'color' =>  'yellow'),
        2 => array (
            'name' =>  'z',
            'nr' =>  '4',
            'color' =>  'red'),
        3 => array (
            'name' =>  'y',
            'nr' =>  '6',
            'color' =>  'green')
    )

);

$color_order = array(
    'red' => 1,
    'green' => 2,
    'blue' => 3,
    'yellow' => 4
);

$new_array = array_map(function($items) use ($color_order){
    $ordered_array = array();
    foreach($items as $item) {
        $item['order'] = $color_order[$item['color']];
        $ordered_array[] = $item;
    }
    usort($ordered_array, "compare"); //sort the array by color order
    return $ordered_array; // the sorted array
}, $arr);


function compare($a, $b){
    if ($a == $b)
        return 0;
    return ($a['order'] < $b['order']) ? -1 : 1;
}

print_r($new_array);
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. I took inspiration from you example and i think i found a somewhat acceptable solution.